# Can't figure out why this drop down categories form is not working. Not sure how to correctly add arguments

Tags: widget, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress recent posts widget with a bunch of different functions for practice. One of the functions I need it to do was allow the admin to specify one category to display via a drop down menu with the categories on it. I asked for help with this here and got an answer but I am not understanding how to get it to work properly. Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: News Recent Posts Widget
Plugin URI: 
Description: A recent post widget with extra functions that allow admin to make changes to certain values
Author: Kevin Ullyott
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://modmacro.com/
*/


class recentpost extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::WP_Widget(
    // or parent::__construct(
        false, 
        'Kevin - Recent Posts Widget',
        array(
            'description' => __('A recent post widget with extra functions that allow admin to make changes to certain values') 

        )
    );
    ;
}

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {


        extract( $args );

        $headline = $instance['headline'];
        $category = $instance['category'];
        $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
        $readmore = $instance['readmore'];


        echo $before_widget;

        echo $before_title;

        echo "<p class=\"headline\">$headline</p>";

        echo $after_title;

        $args = array( 'numberposts' => $numberposts, 'category_name' => $category );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        setup_postdata(get_post($recent['ID']));
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent['ID']) . '" title=" '.esc_attr(get_the_title($recent['ID'])).'" >' .   get_the_title($recent['ID']).'</a> ';
        echo get_the_time('F j, Y', $recent['ID']);
        the_excerpt();
}
wp_reset_postdata();


        echo $after_widget;


    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['headline'] = ( $new_instance['headline'] );
        $instance['category'] = ( $new_instance['category'] );
        $instance['numberposts'] = ( $new_instance['numberposts'] );
        $instance['readmore'] = ( $new_instance['readmore'] );
        return $instance;
    }


    public function form( $instance ) {

        $headline = $instance[ 'headline' ];
        $category = $instance[ 'category' ];
        $numberposts = $instance[ 'numberposts' ];
        $readmore = $instance[ 'readmore' ];

        ?>

<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Headline:' ); ?>
  </label>
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline ); ?>" />
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Category:' ); ?>
</label>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('name' => $this->get_field_name('category'), 'selected' => $category, 'id' => $this->get_field_id('category'), 'class' => 'widefat')); ?>
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberposts' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Number of posts:' ); ?>
</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberposts' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'numberposts' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $numberposts ); ?>" />
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Read More:' ); ?>
</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'readmore' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $readmore ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("recentpost");') );


?>
```

So if you look down at the form for Category I put in a PHP code there to create the drop down menu. It succesfully creates the form and displays the correct categories within the drop down menu but when I save it does not correctly update and makes the widget display nothing.

The user that gave me this code told me this. He said: "function wp_dropdown_categories will bring in the categories but adding the function alone wont save or retrieve the selected category. You'll need to add the name selected and id arguments." But the problem is I do not know how to add the name, selected, and id arguments. Everything I have tried to do has fail so far. Can some one show me the correct way to do this using my code. It would help a lot. I am very new to this and am trying to learn so please provide what I need to do and if you could explain it.

Sorry to ask so much I just enjoy coding and want to know as much as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_dropdown_categories returns the category ID.  so, if your form displaying the correct categories and saving, then its working.  So youll want to look at your query.  It looks like you are currently trying to get categories by `category_name`.

`$args = array( 'numberposts' => $numberposts, 'category_name' => $category );`

change that to

`$args = array( 'numberposts' => $numberposts, 'cat' => $category );